# Ability to flag already flagged posts, comments and answers directly from the flagged posts screen in Tools

Tags: feature-request

If you pull up the flags page, you can see what's been flagged but you can't add another flag without going to the question page.

In some cases this may be necessary to understand the context, but for comments such as:

"I would take my pants off and start masturbating - that ought to get their attention."

I'm really thinking that there is no context that's going to make that acceptable.

Would it be possible to apply flags direct from the flags / tools page?